# How to add a border to a cell when a button is clicked?

Tags: android, mouseevent, touch-event

How do I add a rectangle (border) to cells 3 and 5 after the users clicks on the green button at the left?

Right now I'm just printing "warning" as shown below. I want to make a square specific on cells 3 and 5.

[image: exambple]

```
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<CellVO> transformRowCells(Node node)
    {
        String symbol = Commons.xml_getAttribute(node, "symbol");
        String samount = StringExtra.stringAsMathUserfriendlyWithString( Commons.xml_getAttribute(node, "samount"), symbol );
        String srate = Commons.xml_getAttribute(node, "srate");
        String spl = StringExtra.stringAsRoundedWithString( Commons.xml_getAttribute(node, "spl") );
        String lamount = StringExtra.stringAsMathUserfriendlyWithString( Commons.xml_getAttribute(node, "lamount"), symbol );
        String lrate = Commons.xml_getAttribute(node, "lrate");
        String lpl = StringExtra.stringAsRoundedWithString( Commons.xml_getAttribute(node, "lpl") );

        int lplColor = CommonsParitem.colorForStringFromPL2(lpl);
        int splColor = CommonsParitem.colorForStringFromPL2(spl);
        if(lplColor == 0) lplColor = CommonsParitem.defaultTextColorGray();
        if(splColor == 0) splColor = CommonsParitem.defaultTextColorGray();

//Log.d("custom", node + ", spl: "+spl+", lpl: "+lpl);

        CellVO cell0 = new CellVO(16, symbol, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        CellVO cell1 = new CellVO(13, lamount, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        CellVO cell2 = new CellVO(13, lrate, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        CellVO cell3 = new CellVO(12, lpl, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, lplColor);
        CellVO cell4 = new CellVO(12, samount, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        CellVO cell5 = new CellVO(14, srate, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        CellVO cell6 = new CellVO(13, spl, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, splColor);

// icon cell
        CellVO cell7 = new CellVO();
        cell7.widthPercent = 5;
        cell7.imgIcon = Commons.isTablet() ? R.drawable.tb_table_cell_btn_x : (didPozEdited(node) ? R.drawable.poz_acikislem_edit1 : R.drawable.poz_acikislem_edit0);

        cell7.setCustomEventListener(new CellVO.OnIconTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIconTap(View v) {

                Log.v("Info","Warning");

            }
        });

        ArrayList<CellVO> cells = new ArrayList<CellVO>();
        cells.add(cell7);
        cells.add(cell0);
        cells.add(cell1);
        cells.add(cell2);
        cells.add(cell3);
        cells.add(cell4);
        cells.add(cell5);
        cells.add(cell6);

        return cells;
    }
```

My XML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rectangle.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ff0000"/>
</shape>
```

in your green button `onClick()`

```
TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rowtext3);
t1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rectangle);
```

Comment: Can I write something programtcily without writing anything in the .xml file?

Comment: well as per my knowledge this is the right way and the reduces code.

Comment: hey did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: No. What I am trying to do is once I click on the green button I want to mark the cell 3 and 5 and once I touch the marker I want to make an action for that cell. Can I?

Comment: yes you can... check my answer _in your green button onClick()_ and for onClick for the cell.